How do I setup entity relationships when there are user roles involved?
I am creating a project management application for my portfolio similar to Jira where Users can collaborate on projects, create tickets, leave comments on tickets, etc.. I'm setting up the entity relationships and I'm a bit confused about how to set them up when there are user roles involved. For example, each User can have many projects and each project can have many Users, so there is a many to many relationship. However, since each user needs a specific role for each project, I created a third entity called ProjectUser which has a composite key of both the User id and the Project id and contains a role property.
Users on a project can create tickets, and each ticket has an author and an assignee. This is where I get confused. Should the Author and Assignee for a Ticket be a User or a ProjectUser? Is a ProjectUsers table even the correct way to go about assigning roles to users?
I currently have the Author and Assignee as Users, and entity framework seems to like this. I created a ProjectParticipant class which is a data transfer object for Users on a project that should contain the users name, email, profile picture url, and role. However, since the User entity does not directly contain a role property, when I use automapper to map a User to a ProjectParticipant, it's not able to map the role property. Is there a better/correct way to go about setting up these relationships?

The assignee of a ticket should be the User, unless you want semantics where a ticket is assigned by a User-Project Role.

However, since the User entity does not directly contain a role property - but it should have a ProjectUsers property that represents a collection of all the rows in the linking table, and you can inspect the roles a user has on a particular project by ege theUserYouKnow.UserProjects.Where(up => up.ProjectId = theProjectIdYouKnow).Select(up => up.Role).. But yes you could also have tickets raised by a ProjectUser. If you're going to do that, you might want to change the compound key for a single column one, otherwise you have to start using ProjectId+UserId as an fk in the Tickets table

If you're going to do that, you might want to change the compound key for a single column one - How would I do that? ProjectUsers is a join table between Users and Projects, so wouldn't I have to use UserId+ProjectId as the key?


This is where I get confused. Should the Author and Assignee for a Ticket be a User or a ProjectUser?

This is not a technical modeling question.  Both designs are valid, and have implications on the data changes the model allows.
What should the behavior be for a Ticket if the user who assigns it leaves the project?
Do you want to allow users who aren't on the project to be on a ticket?

If a user creates a ticket and then leaves the project, the ticket should remain in the database, but the reporter should be updated to another user (perhaps the owner of the project). If they are assigned to any tickets, then the assignee property on that ticket should become null since the assignee property is nullable.

Then relating ticket to ProjectUser might be better, as it will help enforce those rules.

Thank you! I agree and have implemented this, although it's a bit challenging given that the key for a ProjectUser is UserId+ProjectId. And since assignee is nullable, I have to add an AssigneeProjectId property that is also nullable on the Ticket entity. Otherwise I get an error because the ProjectId property isn't nullable. It feels messy.
